# Entered company name in Individual Account ( At the time for iphone APP Upload)

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, appstore-approval

Recently I buy a new Individual developer account of $99 and now when I was trying to upload my first app. I got a message i.e.

**What is the company or developer name that you want displayed on the App Store for all of your applications?**

I have heard somewhere if you have Individual account you cannot enter any company name, you have to enter only profile name.

Is it really true ? Because I didn't enter my name. Instead of I have entered my company name and that is accepted when i clicked submit.

My question is: Will this create problem for me in my developer account ? Will be all my apps rejected ?

Comment: If you do enter a company name, check your local laws.  Some legal jurisdictions may require a DBA or fictitious names filing and/or some sort of business license or tax document for doing business under any sort of company name.  Fines for not doing so may apply.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Individual developer account, your real name is always displayed. The iPhone app store app shows only your real name, while iTunes on the computer will display your real name but use your company name to group your apps.

In any case, Apple has a simple and painless process in place to upgrade an Individual account to a Company account (they both cost the same) once you have done the paperwork to turn your company into a legal entity. All you need to do is call the Developer Relations customer service hotline to get the process started.

Comment: What's the developer service hotline? Also, I thought that business accounts costed more.

Comment: **Enterprise accounts** do cost more, but that's for distributing apps within a company. Individual and Company accounts now cost the same ($99/year). Company accounts did cost more than Individual accounts when Apple started the iOS program but now they are the same price. The developer program phone numbers can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.html They are really helpful but they don't answer app review-related questions. :-D

Answer (score 2):

By now apple has removed the opportunity to add a company name (or artist name) for an individual account.

The company name is/was shown as "come from" under the app name. The real name is always displayed under "developer". You can see this in iTunes and in iPhone (at least under iOS6).